# Fish shell error

Tags: shell, ubuntu, fish

I installed [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) which inserted some lines to my `.profile`, I modified them to work with fish shell instead of bash:

```
if [ "$BASH" ]
  if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]
    . ~/.bashrc
  end
end

mesg n or true

export NVM_DIR="/root/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] and . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
```

.. but I still get this error:

```
root@server011 ~# source /root/.profile
[: the last argument must be ']'
```

Comment: You're getting that error because `and` is not a synonym for `&&`. It's a keyword in the fish language that is also a builtin command. You need to put a semicolon between the `]` and the `and` or just put the `and...` on a separate line. Also, as @ridiculousfish pointed out it is unlikely the nvm.sh script is compatible with fish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a missing semicolon:

```
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] ; and . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"
                         ^
```

I'm not sure if `nvm.sh` is fish-compatible. If it is not, fish won't be able to source it.

In that case, you might try [fnm](https://github.com/fisherman/fnm) or [this plugin](https://github.com/fisherman/nvm).